# left outer Join missing records

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to list the missing records in my PartsOnHand. If my inventory table lists an item and it is not related to my PartsOnHand I want to list out which items are missing for each records.

Here is the query I tried using:

```
select * 
from inventory i
left outer join PartsOnHand ph on  i.InName = ph.InName
```

My table structure is as follows:

Inventory:

```
InName
-----------
Wrench
Hammer 
Pen
```

PartsOnHand:

```
id    Inname
------------------
505   Hammer 
505   Wrench
501   Wrench
501   Hammer
```

Desired Results:

```
505   Pen
501   Pen
```

---

Sample Data:

```
Select *
    FROM (
with inventory as (
    select 'Wrench' as InName from dual
    union 
    select 'Hammer' from dual
    union 
    select 'Pen' from dual

    ), partsonhand as (
    select '505' as id, 'Wrench' InName  from dual
    union  
    select '505' as id, 'Hammer' InName from dual
    union 
    select '501' as id, 'Wrench' InName from dual
    union 
    select '501' as id, 'Hammer' InName from dual
    )
    select * 
    from inventory i
    left outer join PartsOnHand ph on  i.InName = ph.InName 

    )
```

Comment: Do you also have a list of ALL id's? Or should we assume that all the id's are present in PartsOnHand? What if there is also an id of 503, which is missing ALL the parts (Hammer, Wrench AND Pen)?

Comment: if there is a id of 503 then I need to list that it is missing all parts in the inventory table.

Comment: Did you read my first question? It is only nine words, it doesn't take long. What is the answer to it?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an additional table ALL_ID with a column ID (primary key, and column id in PartsOnHand pointing to it), which would be the proper setup; OR you want the ID's to be read from table PartsOnHand. I will assume the former; if it's the latter, ALL_ID can be created as a subquery, by selecting distinct id from PartsOnHand

```
select id, inname
from   all_id cross join inventory
where  (id, inname) not in (select id, inname from partsonhand)
;
```

This assumes there are no NULLS in PartsOnHand (there shouldn't be any - otherwise you have data problems).

Comment: Guy - that does compile is that Oracle?

Comment: That is meant to be Oracle, yes. And I think it should compile; I didn't create your tables, but I tested on a very similar arrangement (using the EMP table in the SCOTT schema, present in most Oracle installations). Did you try it? If you did, what happened? ACTUALLY sorry, I missed a pair of parentheses, I will add it now... :(

Comment: ID,iname in the where clause need to be wrapped in ()'s to relate to the not in so... `Where (ID,InName) not in` 2nd all_ID table.. not sure it exists... but to be fair i've not read the entire text yet :P

Comment: @xQbert Right, that's what happens when I need to re-write instead of copying and pasting my tested code  :)  Re: ALL_ID table, I talked about that in the Answer and also in a Comment - and I explained how to work around it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `select id, inname
from   (Select distinct ID from partsOnHand) 
cross join inventory
where  (id, inname) not in (select id, inname from partsonhand)`
appears to do it assuming wrench is both 501 and 505.  If wrench is 505 both times this produces 4 records.  `(iname <> inName)`

Comment: @xQbert - lol, I missed that too ("inname" instead of "iname"), thank you for editing. Same problem  - I SHOULD not be lazy and recreate the OP's data rather than run my tests on different tables. :)

Comment: @mathguy non-issue.  Answer is of quality just needed some "fine tuning"

Comment: sorry it was a typo in the sample data. It appears that the best model for this is the cross join: The answer that xQbert gave of : select id, inname from (Select distinct ID from partsOnHand) cross join inventory where (id, inname) not in (select id, inname from partsonhand)

Comment: @coder32 - xQbert simply wrote out what I said in my answer. But this is why I asked you if there may be OTHER id's, not present in the PartsOnHand table to begin with. You **STILL HAVEN'T** answered my first question to you in Comments under your question: DO YOU HAVE THE id's IN ANOTHER TABLE? If not, how are you going to know about an id like 503 (in my example) which is missing ALL parts (and so will NOT BE in the SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating all of the different possible combinations of `Id` and `InName` via a `CROSS JOIN` and doing a `RIGHT JOIN` to that result:

```
Select  L.*
From    PartsOnHand P
Right Join
(
    Select  Id, InName
    From    Inventory   I
    Cross Join
    (
        Select  Distinct Id
        From    PartsOnHand P
    ) X
) L On  L.id = P.id
    And L.InName = P.InName
Where   P.id Is Null
```

> Results:

```
Id  InName
501 Pen
505 Pen
```

Comment: How so?  It's literally the same as your expected result.

Comment: I gave the sample data in post above. If I were to add your joins it gives me 501, Pen - 505, Pen - 505, Hammer - 501, wrench

Comment: @coder32 Because your sample data doesn't match the tables you provided in the question.  Take a closer look at your `PartsOnHand` query.  You only have `505 Wrench` and `501 Hammer` repeated twice. Because of this, it makes sense that `505 Hammer` and `501 Wrench` are also being returned, as they are missing from your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd to assign the same IDs to different names...  (How do I know the ID of Pen is 505 and 501?) but this delivers the desired results in example:

```
with inventory as (
select 'Wrench' as InName from dual
union 
select 'Hammer' from dual
union 
select 'Pen' from dual

), partsonhand as (
select '505' as id, 'Wrench' InName  from dual
union  
select '501' as id, 'Hammer' InName from dual
union 
select '505' as id, 'Wrench' InName from dual
union 
select '501' as id, 'Hammer' InName from dual
)
select C.ID, I.InName 
from inventory i
LEFT join partsonhand P
 on I.Inname = P.InName
cross join (Select distinct ID from partsonHand) C
Where P.ID is null
order by ID Desc;
```

[image]

Comment: I've show it with the data provided in your constructed set where wrench is listed as 505 twice and in your data where wrench is listed as 505 and 501.  To do this I created partsonhand2 with the data from the table and union-ed the results.

Comment: The id is presumably not associated with the tool names. Rather, they may be (for example) id's for toolboxes, every single one of which SHOULD include one of every tool. This problem is to list which toolboxes are missing which tools.

Comment: ah cool!  Wouldn't have thought about ID for partsOnHand as being a container.

Comment: Cross join seems to be very slow when working large data is there anything that is more efficient?

Comment: Without having a dataset which lists the InNames for each ID I can't think of anything that would be better.  We could make the cross join a left join and set the on condition to 1=1 but I believe the effect for the DBengine would be a cross join so... same performance.  The issue here is we have to "Create" data as we have to create 505 and 501 for pen as it's not defined in your data set.  The best mechanism I know for this is a cross join.